# UICollectionViewController Transition with TLTransitionLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a transition between two `UICollectionViewController`s using the library TLTransitionLayout.

I can transition the layout of the first view controller with no problem. But trying to do the same with the second one crashes the app.

This is my code:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{

    UIView *inView = [transitionContext containerView];
    UIViewController *fromVC = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIView *fromView = [fromVC view];
    UIViewController *toVC  = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *toView = toVC.view;

    self.fromCollectionView = ((UICollectionViewController *)fromVC).collectionView;
    self.toCollectionView = ((UICollectionViewController *)toVC).collectionView;
    self.fromCollectionView.delegate = self;

    //[self.toCollectionView transitionToCollectionViewLayout:self.toCollectionView.collectionViewLayout
    [self.fromCollectionView transitionToCollectionViewLayout:self.toCollectionView.collectionViewLayout
                                                   duration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                                                     easing:CubicEaseOut
                                                 completion:^(BOOL completed, BOOL finished) {
                                                     [inView insertSubview:toView aboveSubview:fromView];
                                                     [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                                                 }];
}



- (UICollectionViewTransitionLayout *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView transitionLayoutForOldLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)fromLayout newLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)toLayout
{
    UICollectionViewTransitionLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewTransitionLayout alloc] initWithCurrentLayout:fromLayout nextLayout:toLayout];
    return layout;
}
```

As it is, it works. If I change the line where it starts the transition to take `toCollectionView` instead of `fromCollectionView` it crashes with the error:

> CRASH: *** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key:
>   transitionLayout)

It seems that the call to `startInteractiveTransitionToCollectionViewLayout` from inside `TLTransitionLayout` library is returning nil, but I don't understand why. My guess is it has something to do with the view controller not being present ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection view needs to have a delegate that returns an instance of `TLTransitionLayout` like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewTransitionLayout *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView transitionLayoutForOldLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)fromLayout newLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)toLayout
{
    NSArray *supplementaryKinds = ...; // optional supplementary view kinds
    return [[TLTransitionLayout alloc] initWithCurrentLayout:fromLayout nextLayout:toLayout supplementaryKinds:supplementaryKinds];
}
```

Based on your code snippet, I see two things:

1. It doesn't look like you've set the delegate on your `toCollectionView`
2. Your `transitionLayoutForOldLayout` method isn't returning an instance of `TLTransitionLayout`

Comment: Thanks, finally after two days of fighting, I went with doing the animation manually. It seems the problem was with that method returning a UICollectionViewTransitionLayout instead of a TLTransitionLayout. Doh!